# accessing dynamic port with gmaven plugin

Tags: maven, groovy, gmaven-plugin

I am starting up my app during the pre-integration-test phase on a dynamic reserved port.  I am using the GMaven plugin and Failsafe to issue a REST call to ensure a successful deployment before proceeding with the tests.  However the port number is still coming back as null. I set the portNum to the Maven environment variable:

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
                <testPort>${portNum}</testPort>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

But when reading the port in the Groovy script I still get null:

```
port = System.getProperty("testPort").toString()
uri = "http://localhost:" + port
log.info(uri)
```

--> http://localhost:null

Any ideas are appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Can you show how you did the settings of the port? What about things like http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/reserve-network-port-mojo.html

Comment: Why the script is accessing `integrationTestPort` while the maven configuration says `testPort` ?

Comment: copy-paste error...sorry

Comment: Yes, the port is reserved with the mojohaus plugin.  ${portNum} will store the assigned port.  It just seems that System.getProperty is not able to pick the info up however.

Comment: Can you explain more how "portNum" is defined and where it's value is configured? It is not clear to me if maven-failsafe-plugin reads portNum or writes portNum